# Docker phpmyadmin after login: 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, jwilder-nginx-proxy

Trying to use docker phpmyadmin to connect several different mysql's both local (containers) and remote servers. All works fine till I start to log in - connecting to remote server works like a charm, problem is to connect local server's containers.
My conf for compose looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin_4.7.6
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - "./conf_phpmyadmin/:/root/confs/"
      - "/sessions"
    networks:
      proxy:
        ipv4_address: "172.18.0.4"
    environment:
      - PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=https://<access-url>/phpmyadmin/
      - PMA_HOSTS=172.21.0.3,192.168.1.65
      - PMA_VERBOSES=LocalMysqlContainer,RemoteMySql
    links:
      - mysql-5.7:mysql

  php7:
    restart: always
    image: php7-phalcon
    hostname: <hostname>
    container_name: <container name>
    expose:
      - 82
    # add static IP in case of restart
    networks:
      network1:
        ipv4_address: "172.21.0.2"
      proxy:
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${EMAIL}

  mysql-5.7:
    restart: always
    image: prod-mysql
    container_name: mysql
    # add static IP in case of restart
    networks:
      network1:
        ipv4_address: "172.21.0.3"
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}

# create custom network
networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: webproxy_proxy
  network1:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.21.0.0/24"
```

- Tried to add mysql container to same network as nginx proxy is (same subnet as phpmyadmin is).
- Tried different ports and IP-s and variations.

Using:

```
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb
docker-py version: 2.5.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Docker itself:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score -2):

Okei, figured it out myself.
Found solution with that help: https://www.dgendill.com/posts/programming/2016-07-03-docker-mysql-notes.html
Not sure though, what exactly helped, but ..